# Accessing field or calling methods in Activity from JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-activity, java-native-interface

I need to access a boolean or int field in activity from jni which is not static, but i get this JNI Warning and throws exception

> JNI WARNING: instance fieldID 0x46488338 not valid for class Ljava/lang/Class;
>        in Lcom/example/filehandler/FileHandlerActivity;.beginFileOperation:(Ljava/lang/String;)I (GetIntField)

I am able to access a static field, why it's not able to access an instance field?

Here is the JNI code i used to access int field in Activity:

```
jint Java_com_example_filehandler_FileHandlerActivity_beginFileOperation(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj,jstring path)
{
  target=(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,path,0);

  jclass cls=(*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
  //jclass cls=(*env)->FindClass(env,"com/example/filehandler/FileHandlerActivity");
  if(cls==NULL)
  {
    LOG_INFO("jni : class not found");
    return 0;
  }


  jfieldID fid=(*env)->GetFieldID(env,cls,"status","I");
  if(fid==NULL)
  {
    LOG_INFO("jni : field not found");
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    LOG_INFO("jni : field found");
  }

  sdcard_status=(*env)->GetIntField(env,obj,fid);
  LOG_INFO("jni : sdcard status = %d",sdcard_status);


  //writeToFile(target);

  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env,path,target);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is `beginFileOperation` declared `static native` in the Java source?  (Please paste the declaration in your question.)

Comment: @fadden i was never bothered of static keyword that i declared in activity, and it worked when i removed it. many thanks.